# Chainlink ATestnetConsumer.sol not Running on Polygon

Tags: chainlink

I had a question in terms of running the ATestnetConsumer.sol through remix on the polygon chain. I was able to run the oracle.sol with no issues and copy down the contract address, and creating a job with it. But when I run the consumer.sol, i get an error for "Internal JSON-RPC error code: -32000" is there an exact issue that can be tracked down to?

Comment: Can you please add your exact contract code that you're running? Also do you get the error on deployment, or on execution of a function? Also is the contract funded with LINK if you're trying to do an API call?

Comment: Just on deployment. Didn’t get to the actual execution. I checked this on my phone I’ll paste the code being run here shortly.

Comment: Here is the code I am looking to deploy on Remix. It compiles fine, but when I go to deploy, it gives a warning and says "this is likely to fail with this error." Being the error I put above.

https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/APIRequests/ATestnetConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setPublicChainlinkToken() function in the constructor that has no parameters is only configured to automatically set the address of the LINK token for Ethereum chains, any other EVM chains need to explicitly pass in the token address. Please update it to pass in the address of the LINK token on Mumbai as a parameter, and try again.

```
setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured something like this was the issue. That makes a lot of sense just didn't know where it was at to fix it. I will test that and verify it works!